# Javascript FileReader.slice(startingByte, endindByte) equivalent in java

Tags: java, filereader

Refer to below specification:

https://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#slice-method-algo

There is a method `FileReader.slice(startingByte, endindByte)` allows to read file from specific `starting byte` to `ending byte`, which is very helpful when reading very big file (1GB+).

What's the equivalent way in java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use seek method, documentation here 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html
http://www.cs.usfca.edu/~parrt/course/601/lectures/io.html